# add text within td tag in IE using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting, client-side-scripting

I have the following HTML code

```
<td class="testclass"> </td>
```

I'm trying with the following jquery:

```
$('testclass').each(function () {
$(this).text("testtext");
});
```

This code is working file in FF but not in IE. Can any one let me know how i can resolve this in IE?

Comment: If that's your exact code, you're missing the `.` in the selector for the class, ie, `$('.testclass')`., which would mean it would not work in any browser (since it instead looks for an element of type `testclass`, like `div`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem in your selector? You need a "." to select on classes, so like:

```
$('.testclass').each(/*etc*/);
```

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - My guess is that either the OP is wrong in their determination (it's not actually working), or their example is not actually demonstrating the real problem (and the `.` is just a mistake in the example). It would be hard to tell exactly without more information and preferably the exact code and possibly a demo to test with.

Comment: I missed . in my post. But the actual problem is that cache in IE is not cleared which is causing some issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a period in the selector.

Also, you don't need to loop at all, the `text` method sets the text of all matched elements:

```
$('.testclass').text("testtext");
```